# $resource error even after adding dependency to ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I am trying to display data in an angular app using $resource, from mongolab. I added dependency to ngResource in the module. Still it says Unknown provider. What is the missing point here?

> '$resource is not defined'

Note: When my factory name was not correct, I was getting error: Unknown provider: employeesProvider <- employees

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 //defining module
 var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

 //defining factory
 app.factory('employees', function () {

    return $resource('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/humanresource/collections/Employees',
                    {apiKey: 'removedmykeyforpostinginSO'}
                  );
 });

 //defining controller
 app.controller('myController', function ($scope, employees) 
 {
    $scope.countries = employees.query();
 });  

</script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
     <div ng-controller="myController">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat = "objCountry in countries" >
            {{objCountry.name}}

        </li>
    </ul>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JSON from Mongolab**

```
[ { "_id" : { "$oid" : "57044f95e4b0427faa38585f"} , "name" : "Lijo" , "age" : "30"} ]
```

Comment: Where is `employees` defined?

Comment: @Lijo you are injecting `employees`, where is the implementation of `employees`? Can you provide that code?

Comment: Change `employees` to `myFactory` or `'myFactory'` to `'employees'`. You also need to inject `$resource` into your factory function, ie `app.factory('employees', function($resource) { ... })`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Also, Angular 1.0.7... wow

Comment: See updated comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [AngulaJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di), the recommended way of declaring factories is:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.factory('serviceId', ['depService', function(depService) {
  // ...
}])
```

I corrected my factory code as below, by injecting $resource:

```
app.factory('employees', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/humanresource/collections/Employees',
                    {apiKey: 'jJbAltZ26vuIrgzUQetXh480JM0q9k6p'}
                  );
 });
```

References:

1. [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)
2. [Tidy Up Your Angular Controllers with Factories and Services](https://www.sitepoint.com/tidy-angular-controllers-factories-services/)
3. [Angular: Passing data back to my controller from a factory ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151465/angular-passing-data-back-to-my-controller-from-a-factory-ajax-call)
4. [Binding variables from Service/Factory to Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023451/binding-variables-from-service-factory-to-controllers)
5. [Angular passing data from factory to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091962/angular-passing-data-from-factory-to-controller)